# Вебпаком пытаюсь использовать стримы из доны в браузере, получаю ошибку: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk

Tags: node.js, потоки-данных, webpack, binary

Пытаюсь в браузере читать блоб и передавать его чанки в стрим, когда пишу в стрим либо ArrayBuffer либо конвертирую его в Uint8Array, stream ругается  типа вы не тот формат передаете `Invalid non-string/buffer chunk` хотя внутри движка ноды, Buffer наследует от класса Uint8Array, а в браузере класса Buffer нет.

Как быть? Как посылать бинарные данные в нодовский стрим, подключеный в браузер, при помощи вебпака?

Answer (score 0):

Вебпак предоставляет модуль который нужно подключить, он эмулирует Buffer из NodeJS, прям в браузере.

```
import {Buffer} from 'buffer'
```

а потом свои чанки прочитанного файла оборачивать в Buffer

```
chunk = new Buffer(bufferArray)
stream.write(chunk)
```